# mvvm-light v4 - well someone has to ask :-)

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I was wondering when the next version of mvvm-light is going to be released?

From what i gather you won't need snippets anymore?

I started to learn mvvm light but that release that 4 is on its way...

Is it probably better to wait and go ahead and learn v3 and the changes won't be major?

Also from what i gather Prism also works with MVVM now but MVVM light is much lighter...

I presume for WP7 programming it is the best there is currently?

Any help or ideas really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVVM Light stands quite well when compared against the available choices.

There is a an overview here you can check out.

[JAPF » Blog Archive » Discover and compare existing MVVM frameworks](http://www.japf.fr/2009/11/discover-compare-existing-mvvm-frameworks/)

I wouldn't say you need to wait for a new version to get started learning. It depends whether you want to release your app sooner or later. If you start now, you will hit the ground running faster with the new release.

It's probably best to ask Laurent directly if he's willing to make any comments on timing of new releases.